# How to capture screenshot of screen casted monitor or TV

Tags: c++, qt, screensharing

I am not able to capture screenshot of that monitor which was connected using screen casting.

QApplication::screens().size(); returns only 1 monitor connected .

How to detect ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this example about screenshot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html)

First of all, you should define a QScreen object like this

```
 QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
```

then

```
 if (const QWindow *window = windowHandle())
  {
    screen = window->screen();
  }

  if (!screen)
  {
    return;
  }
```

then you should have QPixmap object in your header(.h) like **QPixmap _pixmap;**

and finally, you should write this

```
  _pixmap = screen->grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId());
```

when you have another monitor , this means you have 2 window IDs.
when using  **QApplication::desktop()->winId()**, it gets both of them.